# Formidable doesnt install on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, sockets, formidable

I recently went through the node beginner book and I was asked to install formidable for handling file uploads, and I got an error like this

![formidable install][1]

I need your advice as I cannot go on learning it without fixing this error.

1 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200

2 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "formidable"

3 error node v0.12.4

4 error npm  v2.10.1

5 error code EACCES

6 error errno EACCES

7 error syscall connect

8 error Error: connect EACCES

9 error at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)

10 error at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)

11 error  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'connect' }
12 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: did you try run with administrator? as the log stated: Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: You appear to have tried to add a screenshot of the error, but have forgotten to add the link to it. Please always review your questions in the preview before submitting them.

Comment: yes i tried running with administrator

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just don't have access to create files into folder you trying to execute command in.

Change folder or run console from Administrator.

Comment: i tried running from administrator , but it still shows the same error;